# function that takes a nested array and element as an argument, return a new array, if a nested array doesn't contain element it will push it to newArr

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; i++) {
      if (arr[i][j] != elem) {
        newArr.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(filteredArray([
  [3, 2, 3],
  [1, 6, 3],
  [3, 13, 26],
  [19, 3, 9]
], 3));
```

How should I remove that error? If a nested array doesn't contain element it will push it to newArr.

Comment: In your second for loop you're incrementing i, not j

Comment: If `i` and `j` look too similar, consider using more semantic names like `row` and `cell`.

Comment: All those nested arrays contain 3 so are you expecting an empty array?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to increment `j` in that inner loop.
2. You also need to find a way to check to see if `elem` has been found, and *only* if it's been found, to add the nested array to the output.

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let found = false;
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] === elem) {
        found = true;
      }
    }
    if (!found) newArr.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredArray([
  [3, 2, 3],
  [1, 6, 3],
  [1, 6, 4],
  [3, 13, 26],
  [19, 3, 9]
], 3)));
```

A more modern method would be to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the arrays that where `elem` is not [`included`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  return arr.filter(inner => {
    return !inner.includes(elem);
  });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredArray([
  [3, 2, 3],
  [1, 6, 3],
  [1, 6, 4],
  [3, 13, 26],
  [19, 3, 9]
], 3)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
    let newArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == elem) {
                newArr.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}

console.log(filteredArray([
    [3, 2, 3],
    [1, 6, 2],
    [3, 13, 26],
    [19, 3, 9]
], 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  let newArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
  if(arr[i].indexOf(elem) === -1){
    newArr.push(arr[i])
  }
}
  return newArr;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thank you for participating. Some notes, hope you find them helpful. Please remove comments from the code if they are not relevant to the answer (all of them). Also, please always post formatted code (the for block needs to be indented). Finally, instead of just posting the code, you should add text highlighting the difference to the question and other answers (i.e. "you can replace the second loop by using `indexOf()`".